# DL: Fixing random seeds or not?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, hyperparameter

I recently started a project to interpret medical images by classifying them into certain classes. During the experiments I tried out different hyperparameters. To make the different configurations comparable I fixed the random seeds using pytorch-lightning´s `pl.seed_everything(seed=42)`.

As I was quite happy with the current results after iterating different hyperparameters a couple of rounds, I tried out the performance on different random seeds that also initialize the neural network.
The results vary greatly when moving away from the seed I used initially. It seems that during my iterations I overfitted the fixed random seed.

**TLDR**: Is there a way to try out different hyperparameters for neural networks without overfitting **a fixed random seed** while still being able to compare different runs without the need to repeat a single configuration *N* times?

Answer (score 2):

If the overfitting keeps on happening then I would suggest taking a look at the number of hidden layers you're using and the nodes per hidden layer. The error will differ based on seeds but these two (hidden layers and neurons) combining has a bigger impact.

There's a vast literature available online but the suggestion from **Introduction to Neural Networks for Java** by **Jeff Heaton** worked fine for me. You can find that here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140721050413/http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/707

Comment: Thanks for your hint! However, I am not referring to overfitting in the common sense but to overfitting of my hyperparameter configuration to a chosen random initilisation seed.